# lottery of a random number with 2 classes

Tags: java, class, random

I'm trying to create a lottery where a random number is generated (from 20-150) and the code says you won if the number generated is a number 40-50. However, I'm having problems calling my second class in my main method. I'm getting an error saying that "method draw in class Lottery cannot be applied to given types." How can I improve my code?

```
class Main {

Lottery.draw();

}


import java.util.*;

public class Lottery {
  public static void draw(String[] args) {
  int entry1 = (int)(Math.random()*150)+20;
  
  if(entry1>= 40 && entry1<=50){
    System.out.println("You won the lottery!");}
  System.out.println(entry1);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, the statement `Lottery.draw()` occurs straight in the class, without being within a method. That is not valid in Java. Second, `draw` accepts a `String[]`, but you're passing none.

Comment: I guess this is a console-app. So the main-enty-point is "static void draw" ?

What purpose has the class Main?
Is this compile-clean code?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note:

Your call to draw needs to be in the main method and remove the `String[] args` from draw.  You don't need the Main class.

```
public class Lottery { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Lottery.draw(); 
   }
}
```

And to generate a number between 20 and 150 inclusive you need to do the following.

```
 int entry1 = (int)(Math.random()*131)+20;
```

That the random number will be between 0 and 130 inclusive so your number will be between 0+20 and 130+20 inclusive ( 20 <= entry1 <= 150)

Comment: Oh right! Thank you so much for your help! I'm a bit confused though to what the point of String[ ] args is. I thought this was something you had to include when making a new a method. When would I use String[ ] args then? I'm new to this language and it can be confusing sometimes ><

Comment: The String[] args would be used if you wanted to pass a string array to your method.    
Normally this construct is used in the main entry point method so you could then process the arguments as necessary from the command line when you ran your program.  But if they were numbers they would have to be converted.  You could also use this technique for any method.  Since you didn't specify that it was a requirement to pass argument I didn't see the need.  But I also wanted to point out that your random number construct was not quite correct.

Comment: Oh, okay I see that now! Thank you!